After upgrading to 24.04 LTS, desktop "taskbar" is missing
I tried reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop, with no luck.   This is on a Proxmox virtual machine.  Any suggestions on how to get the taskbar back, would be appreciated.

Does it properly work when logging in to a different user account?

Just had that issue. I did the following:
to switch to another virtual terminal.
Ctrl+Alt+F3

In the virtual terminal login with your credentials and then run the following commands:
sudo apt purge ubuntu-session

then
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

finally reboot
sudo reboot

This helpd in my case.
